# Access multiple rear-facing cameras on Android using Unity WebCamDevice

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access the wide-angle lens on Android devices. On iOS, I can find it using:

```C#
Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
```

However, this only returns one rear-facing camera on Android, regardless of the true number of rear-facing cameras.
My AndroidManifest.xml includes [all camera permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element).

My hunch is that this has something to do with [logical vs physical cameras](https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/multi-camera), but Unity provides no documentation or source code to examine whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access to the other cameras and configurations on device, you will have to use AR Foundations. See the CpuImages example and the following script [CameraConfigController.cs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/CameraConfigController.cs)

You can assume that the lower Hz configurations are using the wide angle camera. Here is an example method:

```
    [SerializeField] private ARCameraManager m_CameraManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the <c>ARCameraManager</c>.
    /// </summary>
    public ARCameraManager cameraManager
    {
        get => m_CameraManager;
        set => m_CameraManager = value;
    }
    private int _cachedFramerate = 0;
    private Vector2 _cachedFov;
    private Vector2Int _cachedSize;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while ((cameraManager == null) || (cameraManager.subsystem == null) || !cameraManager.subsystem.running)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        _cachedFramerate = cameraManager.currentConfiguration.Value.framerate.Value;
        _cachedSize = new Vector2Int(cameraManager.currentConfiguration.Value.width, cameraManager.currentConfiguration.Value.height);
        
        if (cameraManager.TryGetIntrinsics(out XRCameraIntrinsics intrinsics))
        {
            _cachedFov = intrinsics.focalLength;
        
        }

        using (var configurations = cameraManager.GetConfigurations(Allocator.Temp))
        {
            if (!configurations.IsCreated || (configurations.Length <= 0))
            {
               StartCoroutine(Start());
               yield break;
            }


            // There are two ways to enumerate the camera configurations.

            // 1. Use a foreach to iterate over all the available configurations
            foreach (var config in configurations)
            {
                if (_cachedSize.x == config.width && _cachedSize.y == config.height && config.framerate < _cachedFramerate)
                {
                    cameraManager.currentConfiguration = config;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        // wait for camera to restart
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
        if (cameraManager.TryGetIntrinsics(out XRCameraIntrinsics newIntrinsics))
        {
            if (newIntrinsics.focalLength.x > _cachedFov.x && newIntrinsics.focalLength.y > _cachedFov.y)
            {
                Debug.Log("Switched to wide angle camera");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Already wide angle camera set");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ARFoundation is a huge binary being added to the codebase. I will test out how much my app packages grow after adding it. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: Happy to help! If you find that it answers your question, make sure to give it an up vote.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a workable solution for me. Some of the issues encountered: (1) the minimum Android API version is 29, excluding some previously-working devices; (2) it uses much more battery; (3) it increases the binary size.

Comment: @artoonie sorry to hear that. The only other options are to create a custom plugin or buy one from the Unity Asset Store.

Comment: Here's to hoping Unity fixes it before I need to do that. I made a bug report here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/webcamdevice-only-returns-one-rear-facing-camera-when-built-on-android